# Searching for Linux Distro by certain criteria

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I've used google, even filtering by adding site:distrowatch.com (this doesn't give many results -- [no linked distros :-(][1]

[1]: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22root%20login%22%20site:distrowatch.com&num=100&newwindow=1&safe=off&hl=en )

I am simply trying to search for a linux distro that:

- Allows root login (preferably defaults to root login)
- Has no systemD
- Fluxbox, or other blackbox based window manager
- Automounts all local partitions
- NOT using Thunar, Spacefm, or Nautilus for default File manager --
  Spacefm default is a plus
- Installs easily from live CD
- Arch based, preferably

Obarun fulfils all these requirements, but the install is a butt-hurt.

Refracta Install is ***SUPERB***, but only Debian based distros use it.

The MAIN issue is why can I not easily search for simple criteria over the 1000's of distros out there. This should not be so hard. I just want a simple quick little system -- under 1000MB download.

Thanks in advance

OldBat

Comment: Why don't you do that in a clean Arch distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Distrowatch has [it's own search](https://distrowatch.com/search.php), with plenty of categories & window managers to filter by, tried there? I looked for any arch based Fluxbox DE Linuxes and it told me these two:

- [BlackArch Linux](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=blackarch)

  - BlackArch Linux is an Arch Linux-based distribution designed for penetration testers and security researchers. It is supplied as a live DVD image that comes with several lightweight window managers, including Fluxbox, Openbox, Awesome and spectrwm. It ships with over a thousand specialist tools for penetration testing and forensic analysis.
- [Parabola GNU/Linux-libre](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=parabola)

  - Parabola GNU/Linux-libre is an unofficial "libre" variant of Arch Linux. It aims to provide a fully free (as in freedom) distribution based on the packages of the Arch Linux project, with packages optimised for i686 and x86_64 processors. The goal is to give the users complete control over their systems with 100% "libre" software. Parabola GNU/Linux-libre is listed by the Free Software Foundation (FSF) as a fully free software distribution. Besides a standard installation CD image, the project also provides a live/rescue DVD image with MATE as the default desktop environment.

But since you'll be installing, you can customize any Linux install to:

- Use whatever file manager & window manager you prefer.
- You actually have to specify `noauto` in the fstab to *stop* auto-mounting on boot or `mount -a`, so automount shouldn't be hard to set up.
- Root login is rarely recommended, but shouldn't be hard to set up either. Though using a permissible `sudo` setup to not ask for a password would be good.

Systemd I'm not so sure, but a search for [arch linux replace systemd](https://www.google.ca/?q=arch+linux+replace+systemd) has lots of promising results, like:

- [Arch linux systemd-free](http://systemd-free.org) - replace it with OpenRC
- The [Without Systemd Wiki](http://without-systemd.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) - extensive list of systemd-free distributions

Could just go for the "most popular" arch based on there, [Manjaro Linux](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=manjaro) and customize it, if you need a popular one that might have more support & a bigger community for help...

Comment: Those are both good variants, but LARGE... Kindly avoid telling a sixty year old woman that root login could possibly be a bad thing -- I personally prefer it and have NEVER had a problem (other than finding a distro that NATIVELY supports it)   There is "Black Arch" but it is HUGE... Black Arch also does not have a transparent installer, you have to google for it :-( There is Kali, also huge. Smaller, Simpler distros like Vsido force a user upon you. Recently Vsido went to PCmanfm, so its a no go now.

Comment: What's wrong with just removing unwanted / un-needed packages after installing? That should shrink the disk footprint a lot. And like I said, PCMan's just a file manager, remove it & install another one.

Comment: Bandwidth. Download time. Install time...   before they changed it, I used to like Vsido very much, as it took a total of 10 mintues from boot to reboot to install completely. But then there was the login as root issue to contend with (but once fixed, it was done)... Obarun is really excellent for all counts I need but I cant force it to install. Also, I have found the "Help" is much better for smaller distro's, it's much more likely to get someone directly on the Team

Comment: @OldBatOnnaRat, in fairness to Xen2050, you never specified that you are a sixty year old woman.  Otherwise, I'm sure he would never have made such an outrageous recommendation.  :-)